# Google Sheets query - conditional limits for ties?

Tags: google-sheets, sql-limit

I have the results of a Google form in a Google sheet, and the form has participants vote on a variety of options.  Results for one question would look like the following:

```
 Activity
-------------
|Bowling    |
|Karaoke    |
|Karaoke    |
|Games Night|
|Bowling    |
|Karaoke    |
```

What I want to do is have a query which will count the votes for each option in the column, then display the top result. So, for the information above, it would display "Karaoke".  I have a query which works for this (below).  I adapted this from a forum response, so I'm not fixed to this if there's a better way to do it.

```
=query(index(if({1,0},unique(A2:A12),countif(A2:A12,unique(A2:GX12)))),"select Col1, Col2 where Col1<>'' limit 1",0)
```

My question is, I can use "limit 1" in the query to only show one item, but what if there is a 2- or 3-way tie for the top choice?  Is there a way that I can show only one option if it's the only max, but show 2 if there's a 2-way tie for max, or 3 if there is a 3-way tie, etc.?

For example, in the data above, it will show just

```
|Karaoke    |
```

But if the next person votes for Bowling, there will be a tie, so then I want to show

```
|Karaoke    |
|Bowling    |
```

Does that make sense?  The solutions I've found so far are in SQL or postgreSQL, and don't work in Google Sheets.

Thanks in advance.
  --Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

`=QUERY(ArrayFormula(QUERY(A:A&{"",""},"select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1")),"select Col1 where Col2="&MAX(COUNTIF(A:A,A:A)),0)`

Comment: YES!  That works!  Amazing!  Thank you.

I had to add a Col1<>'' in the second Select statement to remove blanks, and the COUNTIF needed its own ArrayFormula, but it definitely set me on the right track.  I didn't know you could nest queries like that.

Comment: Another small note for anyone else looking at this, this does not provide a header for the column.  For another use where there is a header, both queries need a ",1" parameter at the end.